# how to try...catch a feign exception and return only the status code and the erro message

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, controller, try-catch

I'm working on a SpringBootApplication. In this app I have 4 micro-services using Feign to communicate between eachothers. In a Controller I have a piece of code like this below, to catch exceptions and return it to the view, in case something is wrong.

```java
        try {
            patientDTO = patientProxyFeign.getPatientById(id);
            noteDTOList = historyProxyFeign.getAll(id);
            assessmentDTO = assessmentProxyFeign.getPatientAssessment(id);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("" + e.getMessage());
            model.addAttribute("errorMsg", e.toString());
            return "error/error";
        }
```

If there is an exception I got a message like this to the view :

```java
feign.FeignException$NotFound: [404] during [GET] to [http://localhost:8081/patient/12000] [PatientProxyFeign#getPatientById(Integer)]: [{"timestamp":"2021-12-16T16:21:27.790+00:00","status":404,"error":"Not Found","path":"/patient/12000"}]
```

What I want to do, is to get only the status code and the message "not found".

Is someone got an idea how to do it ? (Search on google, but seems to be too specific. I probably don't use the right keywords.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the status by calling `e.status()` and then you can `switch`-`case` the status and get a message based on that. You could also build a `Map` of `<Integer, String>` and get the message by status. To read about FeignException more kindly visit https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/blob/master/core/src/main/java/feign/FeignException.java

And it is strongly advisable to be specific about what you `catch`:

```
} catch (FeignException e) {
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to use ```e.status()``` but it's not even recognised by IntelliJ, I'll have a look on what you linked and give a feedback.

Comment: Thanks dude, everything works I just needed to catch a FeignException to be able to get status code (instead of Exception alone)

Comment: @GeoffreyAulombard I'm glad your problem has been resolved.